# typo3 form-action in extbase to another extension

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

So I'm working with typo3 7.6.10 now and I made two extensions. In one view-file (of extension 1), I have a form-field, which should call an action in extension 2.

For some reason however, this action is never reached. Instead, another action from another controller with another name is called.

**Controller** (the one I need)

```
namespace Tronet\Trocomments\Controller;

class TroCommentsManageController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController
{

    public function addCommentAction($post)
    {
        \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump();
        die;

    }
}
```

**Form**

```
<f:form action="addComment" extensionName="Trocomments" pluginName="TrocommentsManage" controller="TroCommentsManage" objectName="post">
```

This generates the following url:

```
?tx_trocomments_trocommentsmanage%5Baction%5D=addComment&tx_trocomments_trocommentsmanage%5Bcontroller%5D=TroCommentsManage&cHash=659e17d494aa4664abe49a551c8f26b4"`
```

This looks correct, but for some reason this point is never reached. The extension is enabled, it is inserted on that page and the TS-files are included as well.

The action is allowed and registered:

**ext_localconf.php**

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin('Tronet.' . $_EXTKEY, 'TrocommentsManage', array(
    'TroCommentsManage' => 'addComment, view',

), // non-cacheable actions
    array(
        'TroCommentsManage' => 'addComment, view',

    ));
```

Thanks for every hint

Comment: Can you show, what is sent via POST to server adn what action is executed instead of expected one?

Answer (score 0):

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin('Tronet.' . $_EXTKEY, 'TrocommentsManage', array(
```

Is incorrectly formatted (`$_EXTKEY` contains the `lowercase_underscore` format of extension key and your vendor-including class name requires the `UpperCamelCase` extension key.

In addition your controller action requires an argument but the action has no phpdoc or type hint. This will confuse Extbase as to whether or not to process the argument.

Lastly, make sure that the target plugin instance exists on the page - or add the `pageUid` argument for `f:form` if the second instance exists on a different page.

But, most likely your issue is a combination of the registration using a bad extension key format and the controller action being insufficiently documented and Extbase not being able to map the argument.